# xEditable only gives textbox despite being set for other values

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, x-editable

In a project I am working on, I dynamically generate an accordion dropdown of values in the database, and I am currently using xEditable in the generated dropdown for in-place editing of the values. However, regardless of what method I use to set the input type (inline html elements or jQuery setting), they always show up as textbox inputs.

Code here:

```
    message.append($('<span />').addClass('').append($('<strong />').addClass('title').html('Project Name: '))
            .append($('<a />').editable().attr("data-pk", projects.ID).attr("data-type", "text")
            .attr("data-name", "ProjectName").attr("data-url", "/ReportServlet")
            .attr("href", "#").html(projects.ProjectName))).append($('<br />'));;
    message.append($('<span />').addClass('').append($('<strong />').addClass('title').html('Infrastructure PM: '))
            .append($('<a />').editable().attr("data-pk", projects.ID).attr("data-type", "text")
            .attr("data-name", "InfraPM").attr("data-url", "/ReportServlet")
            .attr("href", "#").html(projects.InfraPM))).append($('<br />'));;
    message.append($('<span />').addClass('').append($('<strong />').addClass('title').html('Clarity ID: '))
            .append($('<a />').editable().attr("data-pk", projects.ID).attr("data-type", "text")
            .attr("data-name", "ClarityID").attr("data-url", "/ReportServlet")
            .attr("href", "#").html(projects.ClarityID))).append($('<br />'));;
    message.append($('<span />').addClass('').append($('<strong />').addClass('title').html('Project Health: '))
            .append($('<a />').editable().attr("data-pk", projects.ID).attr("data-type", "select")
            .attr("data-name", "ProjectHealth").attr("data-url", "/ReportServlet")
            .attr("data-source", [{value: 0, text: 'Green'}, {value: 1, text: 'Yellow'}, {value: 2, text: 'Red'}])
            .attr("href", "#").html(
                (projects.ProjectHealth == 0) ? '<pre class="green">Green</pre>'
                : (projects.ProjectHealth == 1) ? '<pre class="yellow">Yellow</pre>'
                : (projects.ProjectHealth == 2) ? '<pre class="red">Red</pre>' : "")));
    message.append($('<span />').addClass('').append($('<strong />').addClass('title').html('Project Status: '))
            .append($('<a />').editable().attr("data-pk", projects.ID).attr("data-type", "textarea")
            .attr("data-name", "ProjectStatus").attr("data-url", "/ReportServlet").attr("data-rows", 5)
            .attr("href", "#").html(projects.ProjectStatus))).append($('<br />'));
    message.append($('<span />').addClass('').append($('<strong />').addClass('title').html('Project Schedule: '))
            .append($('<a />').editable().attr("data-pk", projects.ID).attr("data-type", "textarea")
            .attr("data-name", "ProjectSchedule").attr("data-url", "/ReportServlet").attr("data-rows", 5)
            .attr("href", "#").html(projects.ProjectSchedule))).append($('<br />'));;
    message.append($('<span />').addClass('').append($('<strong />').addClass('title').html('Project Hours--DBA: '))
            .append($('<a />').editable().attr("data-pk", projects.ID).attr("data-type", "text")
            .attr("data-name", "ProjectHoursDBA").attr("data-url", "/ReportServlet")
            .attr("href", "#").html(projects.ProjectHoursDBA))).append($('<br />'));;
    message.append($('<span />').addClass('').append($('<strong />').addClass('title').html('Project Hours--Infra: '))
            .append($('<a />').editable().attr("data-pk", projects.ID).attr("data-type", "text")
            .attr("data-name", "ProjectHoursInfra").attr("data-url", "/ReportServlet")
            .attr("href", "#").html(projects.ProjectHoursInfra))).append($('<br />'));;
    message.append($('<span />').addClass('').append($('<strong />').addClass('title').html('Project Hours--PM: '))
            .append($('<a />').editable().attr("data-pk", projects.ID).attr("data-type", "text")
            .attr("data-name", "ProjectHoursPM").attr("data-url", "/ReportServlet")
            .attr("href", "#").html(projects.ProjectHoursPM))).append($('<br />'));;
    message.append($('<span />').addClass('').append($('<strong />').addClass('title').html('Project Completion Date: '))
            .append($('<a />').editable().attr("data-pk", projects.ID).attr("data-type", "datetime")
            .attr("data-name", "ProjectCompletionDate").attr("data-url", "/ReportServlet")
            .attr("href", "#").html(date)));
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry. I'm wondering if there are any hints or thoughts as to why the "data-type" attributes aren't setting textareas or datepickers or dropdowns when they should be. Instead, all I'm getting is textboxes.

Comment: let us see your script where you are triggering the x-editable plugin thanks.

Comment: It is located right here. I dynamically generate "message" which gets pushed into an accordion dropdown list. Each message.append() is a <span> including the <a> which is triggered editable() in-line.

`message.append($('<span />').addClass('').append($('<strong />').addClass('title').html('Project Name: '))
            .append($('<a />').`editable()`.attr("data-pk", projects.ID).attr("data-type", "text")
            .attr("data-name", "ProjectName").attr("data-url", "/ReportServlet")
            .attr("href", "#").html(projects.ProjectName))).append($('<br />'));;`